# Python Development.Module not found by CMAKE while configuring ELMERFEM w/ VTK

Tags: python, cmake, vtk

I'm trying to build ElmerFEM with VTK as a support package for the the GUI. However, I'm unable to make it past the configuration step because `Development.Module` cannot be found by the VTK cmake files.

I'm using CMAKE-3.16.3 and VTK-9.2 on Ubuntu 20.04.
I compiled VTK-9.2 myself.

The error call stack that is produced is as follows

```
CMake Error at cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:108 (message):
  Could NOT find Python3 (missing: Development.Module) (found suitable
  version "3.9.5", minimum required is "3.9")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:315 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/local/lib/cmake/vtk-9.2/patches/3.23/FindPython/Support.cmake:3222 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  /usr/local/lib/cmake/vtk-9.2/patches/3.23/FindPython3.cmake:490 (include)
  /usr/local/lib/cmake/vtk-9.2/VTK-vtk-module-find-packages.cmake:303 (find_package)
  /usr/local/lib/cmake/vtk-9.2/vtk-config.cmake:152 (include)
  ElmerGUI/CMakeLists.txt:106 (FIND_PACKAGE)
```

I have `python3.9-dev` and `python3.9` installed. For reference I can demonstrate this through `dpkg -l python3.*` which produces

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                      Version                 Architecture Description
+++-=========================-=======================-============-============================================================================
un  python3.1                 <none>                  <none>       (no description available)
un  python3.6-2to3            <none>                  <none>       (no description available)
un  python3.7-2to3            <none>                  <none>       (no description available)
ii  python3.8                 3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.8 amd64        Interactive high-level object-oriented language (version 3.8)
un  python3.8-apt             <none>                  <none>       (no description available)
un  python3.8-cairo           <none>                  <none>       (no description available)
un  python3.8-cups            <none>                  <none>       (no description available)
un  python3.8-dbus            <none>                  <none>       (no description available)
ii  python3.8-dev             3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.8 amd64        Header files and a static library for Python (v3.8)
un  python3.8-distutils       <none>                  <none>       (no description available)
un  python3.8-doc             <none>                  <none>       (no description available)
un  python3.8-gdbm            <none>                  <none>       (no description available)
un  python3.8-lib2to3         <none>                  <none>       (no description available)
ii  python3.8-minimal         3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.8 amd64        Minimal subset of the Python language (version 3.8)
un  python3.8-protobuf        <none>                  <none>       (no description available)
un  python3.8-renderpm        <none>                  <none>       (no description available)
un  python3.8-reportlab-accel <none>                  <none>       (no description available)
un  python3.8-talloc          <none>                  <none>       (no description available)
ii  python3.8-venv            3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.8 amd64        Interactive high-level object-oriented language (pyvenv binary, version 3.8)
ii  python3.9                 3.9.5-3ubuntu0~20.04.1  amd64        Interactive high-level object-oriented language (version 3.9)
ii  python3.9-dev             3.9.5-3ubuntu0~20.04.1  amd64        Header files and a static library for Python (v3.9)
un  python3.9-distutils       <none>                  <none>       (no description available)
un  python3.9-doc             <none>                  <none>       (no description available)
un  python3.9-gdbm            <none>                  <none>       (no description available)
un  python3.9-lib2to3         <none>                  <none>       (no description available)
ii  python3.9-minimal         3.9.5-3ubuntu0~20.04.1  amd64        Minimal subset of the Python language (version 3.9)
ii  python3.9-venv            3.9.5-3ubuntu0~20.04.1  amd64        Interactive high-level object-oriented language (pyvenv binary, version 3.9)
```

When I have searched for help about the vast majority of it is how to actually write cmake scripts with `find_package(Python3 COMPONENTS Interpreter Development` which I'm fairly certain is already done by the VTK developers.

I have already found references elsewhere to set

cmake .. -DPython3_EXECUTABLE= -DPython3_INCLUDE_DIRS=

with one also referencing some additional ones

`-DPython3_LIBRARY=<absolute path>` and `-DPython3_LIBRARY_DIRS=<absolute path>`.

However, by using

```
cmake .. -DPython3_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python3.9 \
-DPython3_INCLUDE_DIRS=/usr/include/python3.9 \
-DPython3_LIBRARY=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.9.so.1 \
-DPython3_LIBRARY_DIRS=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
```

However, using this didn't change the error produced at the beginning of this post.

I have very little cmake experience, and I don't even know what file or directory is trying to be found when searching for `Development.Module`. How do I remedy this problem?

EDIT: I updated cmake to the latest version (3.26.4) in hopes that it would fix the issue. There seems to have been some issues with older releases, but it did not fix my issue. However, it did move around the call stack.

The new call stack is below

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.26/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  Could NOT find Python3 (missing: Development.Module)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.26/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:600 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.26/Modules/FindPython/Support.cmake:3766 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.26/Modules/FindPython3.cmake:551 (include)
  /usr/local/lib/cmake/vtk-9.2/VTK-vtk-module-find-packages.cmake:303 (find_package)
  /usr/local/lib/cmake/vtk-9.2/vtk-config.cmake:152 (include)
  ElmerGUI/CMakeLists.txt:106 (FIND_PACKAGE)
```